# In terms of relational databases is a Relvar the equivalent to a Schema?

Tags: schema, relational-theory

I've been reading up on relational databases and the term Relvar and schema keeps coming up. From my understanding:

```
A relvar is a variable holding a relation. 

A schema is a logical definition of a table.
```

so I tried to imagine this in programming terms and I came up with this:

```
Relvar a = [Table 1 - Attributes a,b,c etc etc]
Schema b = [Table 1 - Attributes a,b,c...]
```

Is there any real difference?

Comment: Do you have a reference for that definition of schema?

Comment: It probably depends how academic you want to get but 'relvar' appears to be another way to refer to a relation which maps most closely to a base table in terms of SQL. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relvar for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

No, a relvar is not equivalent to a schema.

A schema is a description of the structure and constraints of a database. In a relational database, this might manifest as the `CREATE TABLE` statements, the column datatypes and null constraints, foreign key constraints, and so on.

Casually, you might say that a table "has a schema," or ask, "what's the schema of that table?" In that context, we're looking at one part of an overall database schema - just the `CREATE TABLE` statement, column datatypes, constraints, etc.

Regarding *relvars*, consider a "regular" variable in programming. When we see `int x = 2`, we know that `x` is the variable, and that `2` is a value. Consider that we can assign a completely new value to `x`, eg `x = 42`.

A relvar is a relation variable. It has a name, which happens to be the name of the table. It has a domain (like the `int` datatype above) which is the structure and datatypes of the columns. It has values, which is the collection of tuples (rows) that happen to "be in the table" at any point in time.

In the most simple sense, a relvar is the name of the table. A relation would then be the collection of rows in the table at a particular point in time.